# PostScript tokens "=string", "=only", etc

Tags: postscript

I am working with a PostScript document that contains tokens such as =string, =only, and ==only.  What do these tokens signify?  If you can help me, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

These are Ghostscript-specific, non-standard, PostScript operators; you shouldn't be using them, nor should any PostScript program.

It is possible (but in my opinion inadvisable, see below) to use them if the code carefully guards against their use on a PostScript interpreter which is not Ghostscript, or defines implementations of them when run on a PostScript interpreter other than Ghostscript (which is entirely safe). In which case you need to read the PostScript program to find out what the implementation there does.

Even when you know you are going to run the PostScript program through Ghostscript and not any other PostScript interpreter you should not use any internal function or operator which is not documented in Language.htm as any non-standard PostScript operators which are not defined in that document are subject to change/removal without notice.

Answer (score 2):

`=string` was present in Adobe interpreters as the internal buffer that `==` uses for formatting. There's probably no good reason to use it, despite any claims I (or others) have made elsewhere on the internet.

`=only` is Ghostscript-specific and does the same job as `=` but without printing a newline at the end. There is an equivalent in Adobe interpreters called `=print`.

`==only` is Ghostscript-specific and does the same job as `==` but without printing a newline at the end. I am not aware of an equivalent in Adobe interpreters.

As Ken says, these are non-standard and not portable to other interpreters than Ghostscript. But IMO they are incredibly useful and ought to be standardized (howsoever unlikely that is).

The book *Inside PostScript* describes the use of `=string` and `=print` inside the `==` procedure as implemented in Adobe interpreters.

*Edit:*

Here's a portable implementation using slightly different names (`=nonl ==nonl`) so as not to conflict with ghostscript. (Error reports are printed using `==only` so if you replace that, *and* screw it up, you don't get error reports!)

```
%!
% Portable implementation of gs's marvelous =only and ==only
/=buffer 256 string def
/=nonldict
    <<
        /operatortype { pop (-oper-) print }
        /filetype { pop (-file-) print }
        /nametype { dup xcheck not {(/)print} if //=buffer cvs print }
        /stringtype { { print } stopped { pop (-string-) print } if }
        /integertype { //=buffer cvs print }
        /realtype { //=buffer cvs print }
        /arraytype { pop (-array-) print }
        /packedarraytype 1 index
        /dicttype { pop (-dict-) print }
        /booleantype { {(true)}{(false)} ifelse print }
        /nulltype { pop (null) print }
        /marktype { pop (-mark-) print }
        /savetype { pop (-save-) print }
    >> def
/=nonl {
    //=nonldict 1 index type get exec
} def

/==nonldict
    <<
        /operatortype { pop (-oper-) tprint }
        /filetype { pop (-file-) tprint }
        /nametype { dup xcheck not {(/)tprint} if //=buffer cvs tprint }
        /stringtype { dup rcheck { dostring }{ (-string-) tprint } ifelse }
        /integertype { //=buffer cvs tprint }
        /realtype { //=buffer cvs tprint }
        /arraytype { dup rcheck not { pop (-array-) tprint }{
                     dup xcheck { ({) tprint doarray (}) tprint }{
                                  ([) tprint doarray (]) tprint
                   } ifelse } ifelse }
        /packedarraytype 1 index
        /dicttype { pop (-dict-) tprint }
        /booleantype { {(true)}{(false)} ifelse tprint }
        /nulltype { pop (null) tprint }
        /marktype { pop (-mark-) tprint }
        /savetype { pop (-save-) tprint }
        /tprint {
            charcount 1 index length add 80 gt {
                (\n) print
                /charcount 1 index length def
            }{
                /charcount charcount 2 index length add def
            } ifelse
            print
        }
        /dostring {
            (\() tprint
            {
                dup 32 lt 1 index 126 gt or {
                    (\\) tprint
                    1000 add
                    //=buffer cvs
                    1 1 index length 1 sub getinterval
                    tprint
                }{
                    ( ) dup 0 4 3 roll put tprint
                } ifelse
            } forall
            (\)) tprint
        }
        /doarray {
            dup length 0 eq {pop}{
                dup 0 get dup type exec
                1 1 index length 1 sub getinterval
                {
                    ( ) tprint
                    dup type exec
                } forall
            } ifelse
        }
    >> def
/==nonl {
    //==nonldict begin
        /charcount 0 def
        dup type exec
    end
} def
```