# Equivalent of == when writing to a file

Tags: postscript

Is there a direct way to get that which == (or =) writes to %stdout written instead to a file?
The ability to capture the output to %stdout in a string (and then use writestring) would satisfy me as sufficiently direct.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to redefine/overload the `==` operator. `cats` (concatenate) and `cvsx` are helpers. The size of the string buffer of `cvsx` (256) may need to be adjusted.
You can of course use another name for the operator instead of `==`.

```
%!
/==
{
  16 dict begin
    /v exch def

    % helpers
    /cats
    {
        /S2 exch def /S1 exch def
        S1 length dup S2 length add string
        dup 0 S1 putinterval 
        dup 3 2 roll S2 putinterval 
    } def
    /cvsx { 256 string cvs } def

    % formatters
    /integertype { v cvsx } def
    /realtype    { v cvsx } def
    /stringtype  { (\() v cats (\)) cats } def
    /booleantype { v {(true)} {(false)} ifelse } def
    /nametype    { (/) v cvsx cats } def
    /nulltype    { (null) } def

    % more type formatters here 

    {
        v type exec
        (\r\n) cats
        /logf (/path/to/ps.log) (a+) file def
        logf exch writestring
        logf closefile 
    }
    stopped 
    {
        (Warning: ) v type cvsx cats ( logging not available\r\n) cats
        print flush
    } if
  end
} bind def

% Unit test
100 ==
123.45 ==
(string) ==
true ==
/BigName ==
null ==
[1 2 3] ==

pstack
```

Comment: Good stuff. I have [an implementation of `==only` and `=only`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58002005/733077) that might give you some more ideas. It covers more types and does it without concatenating (you're just going to print them shortly afterword).